# Выполнение персональных действий без регистрации

Tags: авторизация

Недавно увидел интересную, но очень простую реализацию (пока выдавать не буду).

Есть сайт, есть некоторые действия (например создание тикета, возможно запись в записной книге) и есть пользователь.

Вопрос как правильно организовать авторизацию без регистрации пользователя (т.е. никаких форм регистрации и паролей).

Если не понятно спрашивайте, постараюсь более понятно объяснить вопрос.

Comment: @Сергей - Вы просто хотели услышать именно такой ответ (Ozim). Интересно, а если пользователь поменяет браузер, у него в "Избранном" файрфокса появится ссылка из "Избранного" оперы или ИЕ? По-моему нет... Чем же тогда хуже куки? К тому же можно объединить эти два подхода, сохранять в куки **все** полученные тикеты, а в ссылках - конкретно один.... И при наличии куки, предложить пользователю выбрать какой тикет он хочет посмотреть, а при наличии тикета в ссылке - отображать именно этот тикет...

Comment: В ответе Ozim (вернее в комментарии) содержится самый лучший вариант, который был предложен. Ссылка отправляется на почту. Т.е. пользователю не надо регистрироваться, он всегда может войти в систему по этой ссылке и посмотреть тикет, при этом если он сменит браузер ничего страшного. Самый плохой вариант - удаление письма. Если допилить куками - можно просмотреть все отправленные тикеты с текущей почты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Генерируйте ему уникальный ключ автоматом после создания тикета, пусть его вводит и будет радость.

Comment: Интересный вариант, но что, если пользователь его потеряет?

Comment: Тогда организуйте вход, с использованием НЕ логина, а email, и шлите ему ключ также на email, если Ваша авторизация не подразумевает входа, а только запись (тикет?), т.е. ничего кроме текста нет, то
- генерируем ключ
- создаем прямую ссылку с передачей ключа в GET
- даем ему ссылку, и предлагаем добавить ее в закладки

Comment: Как ни странно именно так реализована система в тикетах WebMoney)

Comment: Именно добавление в закладки и хотел предложить. Ozim, Вы меня опередили! )) +
@Сергей - Вы просто хотели услышать именно такой ответ. Интересно, а если пользователь поменяет браузер, у него в "Избранном" файрфокса появится ссылка из "Избранного" оперы или ИЕ? По-моему нет... Чем же тогда хуже куки? К тому же можно объединить эти два подхода, сохранять в куки **все** полученные тикеты, а в ссылках - конкретно один.... И при наличии куки, предложить пользователю выбрать какой тикет он хочет посмотреть, а при наличии тикета в ссылке - отображать именно этот тикет...

Answer (score 2):

А таким образом не увеличится возможность потери личных данных, информации?

Comment: В той реализации которую я видел не теряется.

Answer (score 1):

куки +, возможно, ip. При подключении пользователя проверяем, есть ли куки с UID? Если есть, значит пользователь у нас не в первый раз, предоставляем ему возможности, связанные с UID. Если UID не найден - генерируем новый UID, устанавливливаем куки. Вуаля. У нас новый "зарегистрированный" пользователь...

Только две проблемы:
а. Обозреватель пользователя может не поддерживать куки/либо они могут быть отключены.
б. пользователь может сам потереть свои куки тем самым "потерЕв" "регистрацию"...

Comment: Ход мыслей интересный, но действительно мы не можем идентифицировать так пользователя. Например если он сменит браузер. Он не сможет увидеть ответ на тикет.

Answer (score 1):

Выдать пользователю уникальный идентификатор, записать в куки.

Чтобы пользователь не смог потереть куки, пишем синхронизатор между "флеш куками" и обычными куками на ActionScript и на JavaScript. Синхронизируем их раз в секунду (можно и несколько раз в секунду), в результате шанс потерять куки в разы уменьшается, особенно на тех браузерах где одновременно потереть стандартный куки и "куки флеша" не возможно.

Материал по теме:

- [Local Shared Objects — Флеш куки](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/Flash_Platform/111176/)
- [JFStorage: Альтернатива cookies](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/personal/29376/)

Comment: цитата: но действительно мы не можем идентифицировать так пользователя. Например если он сменит браузер. Он не сможет увидеть ответ на тикет.

Comment: Перейдите по первой ссылке и прочтите [первый коммент][1].

[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/Flash_Platform/111176/#comment_3545181

Comment: Что если пользователь переставит систему? Или зайдет с другого компьютера?

Comment: Блин а что если он ударится головой и с ним случится амнезия, а в это время на планету упадет астероид из армагеддона и Брюса Уиллиса не окажется рядом, и юзеру нахрен разможжит компьютер? Не сходите с ума, господа )

Comment: Ну почему же?) Я считаю надо рассматривать все варианты.

Comment: Хм, что же...тогда попробуйте авторизацию через соц сети, нынче редко кто не зареган в соц сетях, а чтобы подключить как можно больше соц сетей к ресурсу обратите внимание loginza.ru

Answer (score -1):

Можно [совместить](http://dwlessons.ru/php/registraciya-i-avtorizaciya-v-1-forme.html) всё в одной форме. Быстро и просто.

Comment: Еще раз повторяю никаких регистраций и паролей